# Understanding Document Library Better

Tags: 2010, document-library

In SharePoint 2010, I have a document library to store some pdf, docs files. I also have some other custom columns in the document library.

1)  What is the maximum size / character I can give it to a file name / Document Name?

2)  What is the maximum file size I can store in a row/item?

3)  What is the maximum file size I can store in a document library?

4)  What is the maximum no of rows I can store in a document library?

5)  I have created a custom column for storing some comments on a file. How many characters will be ideal for that column?

6) If I have a date column in the document field, can I move some particular documents from a range of date to other document library through code? if yes how difficult it will be? the other document library also have same fields as in the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It depends on some factors: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919564.aspx
2. I don't understand this question clearly
3. 2 GB (but the default restriction is 50 MB) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx
4. 30 000 000 per list/library is recommended but there's no hardcoded limit http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx
5. Don't know exactly
6. It's easy, all you must do is to define properly CAML query based on desired range and use SPListItem.CopyTo or SPFile.MoveTo (not sure exactly)

Comment: Thanks Alex, 2nd question was, is there any limit of file size to store in a list's row?  Whether share Point gives any notification, when it reaches its 2 GB size limit?

Comment: You simply cannot upload too big file - you will see this error message: http://aronduncan.wordpress.com/2011/03/08/sharepoint-2010-maximum-file-size-error/ BTW here's the instructions to change default limit: http://www.sharepointedutech.com/2010/02/23/how-to-change-the-maximum-file-size-upload-in-sharepoint-2010/